Lanelet2 for Path Planning
I have created a lanelet2 map for autonomous path planning but I dont know how to use this map. I have searched all over the web but couldn't find anything.
System Info :
ROS Noetic
Ubuntu 20.04
I tried some packages on Github but I got errors during catkin_make and couldn't figure it out.
